# Subtracting square roots

Tags: trigonometry, arithmetic, radicals

I'm studying trigonometry but I don't understand one example I have here:

$\cos(\frac{5}{12}\pi) = \cos(\frac{1}{6}\pi + \frac{1}{4}\pi)$

$= \cos(\frac{1}{6}\pi)\cos(\frac{1}{4}\pi) - \sin(\frac{1}{6}\pi)\sin(\frac{1}{4}\pi)$

$=(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{3})(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2})-(\frac{1}{2})(\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{2})$

$=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{3}-1)$

I got the result $\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{6}-\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{2}$, which is the same as the result above. However, I don't know how this calculation became $=\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{3}-1)$.

Please, anyone can explain to me?

Comment: Do you know that $\sqrt{a\cdot b}=\sqrt{a}\cdot \sqrt{b}$ for $a,b\geq0$

Comment: Take the common factor $\frac14 \sqrt{2}$...

Answer (score 1):

As fast as light:

$$\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{6} - \frac{1}{4}\sqrt{2} = \frac{1}{4}(\sqrt{6} - \sqrt{2})$$

Now you will use the property $\sqrt{6} = \sqrt{3\cdot 2} = \sqrt{3}\cdot \sqrt{2}$ to get the result, i.e.

$$\frac{1}{4}\sqrt{2}(\sqrt{3} - 1)$$